# Why does this app have a plugins directory, but no reference in gem file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to understand this open source app on github, it has a gem file:

https://github.com/bestbuyremix/BBYIDX/blob/3f8d378ef318544411aa887c4ef71e1ab8a9efd0/.gems

And a plugins folder:

https://github.com/bestbuyremix/BBYIDX/tree/3f8d378ef318544411aa887c4ef71e1ab8a9efd0/vendor/plugins

Why would you want to do this?  Does this make upgrading the plugins harder?

When you reference a gem, from what I understand, it downloads the files and stores them at a global level (gemset if using rvm etc), so I guess loading it as a plugin gives you access to the source to modify?

**i.e Why go with gem versus a plugin or visa versa?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins give you the flexibility of being able to just copy your app somewhere else and poof! it's all ready to go.

Gems on the other hand, force you to a) download them to every single piece of hardware that your app is running on via `rake gems:install` and b) force you to keep track of which packages are installed on which system.

With plugins, you know that when you stick it in your `vendor` directory, it will work immediately.

Comment: makes sense, but how to you manage versions etc?  I guess each folder is a git repo then?